# pacct file on gentoo gobbles up lots of disk space, can I nullyfy it?

Tags: linux, disk-space, gentoo

root@GentooLinux_18:41:46_Wed Apr 03:/var/account#du -shc *

2.3G    pacct

2.3G    total

Wondering!!

And I am getting this :

```
couldn't open file '@ACCT_FILE_LOC@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, got it! Here it is:

```
dump-acct pacct
```

Comment: Could you make this more of a teachable moment by expanding the answer to explain what this does and why it solves the problem?  Thanks.  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/851629)

Comment: Sure. My apology for being too short. I was getting the error mentioned in the post, that it gobbles up disk space like 2.3 GB and I didn't install the binary dump-acct to see the pacct file, which is a binary file. This file contains all the command run by the process, kinda command logging facility. With the help of dump-acct binary, you can clearly see the format, when the command run. All I had to do, get into the dir and fire that command against that file to see the output informative manner. This stuff can be used in security purpose too. Lastly, I can easily nullify it by #>pacct